# Remove separator from integer

Tags: php

How can I remove the comma separator from a number

e.g. 40,000 resulting in 40000 in php?

```
function cleanData($a) {
     $a = (int)str_replace( '.', '', $a );
     return $a;
}
```

I've tried using this function only when I compare the result (===) of `cleanData($a)` with 40000 it doesn't match types?

Comment: You're replacing a dot instead a comma....

Comment: what is your comparision condition??

Comment: I suggest printing out the value next time to make sure it's equal to what you expect it to be, as that would have solved this problem for you.

Comment: My mistake just noticed that (,) issue. Is it right to use str_replace even though the value is an integer?

Comment: @RobMorris The value is a string, NOT an integer, until you typecast the result of the str_replace. Integers can't have commas, hence why its a string.

Comment: I'm being dumb today thanks. Just found out the value is was matching the converted string to was not an integer. I used `(int)` to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function cleanData($a) {
     $a = (int) str_replace( ',', '', $a );
     return $a;
}
```

First of all, you want to replace commas (`,`), not periods. Second, `===` checks types as well as value so you must typecast from a string to an integer using `(int)`. You did that part, but you weren't replacing commas so the value was 40, not 40000.

Example:

```
<?php
var_dump((int) str_replace( '.', '', '40,000')); // int(40)
var_dump((int) str_replace( ',', '', '40,000')); // int(40000)
```